# Nested apply concatenation

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create loop for building custom HTML Table. I am having issue in nested lapply.

**Code**

```
library(htmltools)
dataframe <- iris[1:5,]
tags$tbody(
  apply(dataframe,1, function(x) { tags$tr(list('class = "Row"',
                                                lapply(colnames(dataframe), function(x1) glue::glue("data-{x1}="))),
                                           lapply(x, function(y) tags$td(y)))})
)
```

**Desired Output**

```
 <tr class = "Row"
    data-Sepal.Length=5.1
    data-Sepal.Width="3.5"
    data-Petal.Length="1.4"
    data-Petal.Width="0.2"
    data-Species= "setosa">
    <td>5.1</td>
    <td>3.5</td>
    <td>1.4</td>
    <td>0.2</td>
    <td>setosa</td>
  </tr>
```

**What I am getting as of now -**

```
 <tr>
    class = "Row"
    data-Sepal.Length=
    data-Sepal.Width=
    data-Petal.Length=
    data-Petal.Width=
    data-Species=
    <td>5.1</td>
    <td>3.5</td>
    <td>1.4</td>
    <td>0.2</td>
    <td>setosa</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: May I ask whats the motivation to do this? As you probably know `renderTable` creates HTML tables from data.frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(htmltools)
dataframe <- iris[1:5,]
tags$tbody(
  apply(dataframe,1, function(x){
    attributesNames <-
      c("class", paste0("data-", colnames(dataframe)))
    attributes <- setNames(c("rovv", as.character(x)), attributesNames)
    cells <- unname(lapply(x, function(y) tags$td(y)))
    args <- c(attributes, cells)
    do.call(tags$tr, args)
  })
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution using `paste0` and `sprtinf`.

```
dataframe <- iris[1:5,]

htmltools::HTML(apply(dataframe, 1, function(x) {
  sprintf('\n<tr class = "Row" \n %s \n </tr>', 
         paste0(c(paste0(
           sprintf('\tdata-%s="%s"', names(dataframe), x), collapse = '\n'),
         paste0(
           sprintf('<td>%s</td>', x), collapse = '\n')), collapse = '\n'))
  
}))

#<tr class = "Row" 
#   data-Sepal.Length="5.1"
#   data-Sepal.Width="3.5"
#   data-Petal.Length="1.4"
#   data-Petal.Width="0.2"
#   data-Species="setosa"
#<td>5.1</td>
#<td>3.5</td>
#<td>1.4</td>
#<td>0.2</td>
#<td>setosa</td> 
# </tr> 
#<tr class = "Row" 
#  data-Sepal.Length="4.9"
#...
#...
```

Answer (score 1):

The attributed of the tags have to be an extra argument while you supplied them as if they were supposed to be a new tag. The solution tried to isolate the different parts so that one can see how it works.

The solution adds all those arguments to a list that we want to pass over to `tags$tr` and the uses `do.call`.

```r
library(htmltools)

GenerateAttributes <- function(xNames, x) {
  names(x) <- paste("data", xNames, sep = "-")
  x
}

GenerateRow <- function(x, xNames) {
  Args <- list(lapply(x, function(y) tags$td(y)))
  Args <- c(Args, class = "Row")
  Args <- c(Args, GenerateAttributes(xNames, x))
  do.call(tags$tr, Args)
}

dataframe <- iris[1:5,]
tags$tbody(
  apply(dataframe, 1, GenerateRow, names(dataframe))
)
```

```
<tbody>
<tr class="Row" data-Sepal.Length="5.1" data-Sepal.Width="3.5" data-Petal.Length="1.4" data-Petal.Width="0.2" data-Species="setosa">
<td>5.1</td>
<td>3.5</td>
<td>1.4</td>
<td>0.2</td>
<td>setosa</td>
</tr>
...
</tbody>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>